# textField textWidth is incorrect ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a dynamic textField using a postscript font (using the Classic font engine in CS5). I created the textField at author time. When I try to determine the actual width of the textField using the textField.textWidth property, the returned width is wildly wrong. For example, the text as displayed on screen has an approximate width of 350 pixels. but the returned width is only 150 pixels. I have tried switching fonts, and using the TextLineMetrix to no avail.

Any ideas why I am not getting an accurate width?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure you set the autoSize property of the text field, this will cause flash to recognize the width as the width of the text instead of the width of the containing text field.  Try something like this...

```
myTextField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
trace(myTextField.textWidth);
```

Answer (score 2):

I find that getBounds give the closest results:

```
var bounds:Rectangle = textfield.getBounds(textfield.parent);
```

Comment: That .textWidth property was giving me the weirdest results (mostly larger) but this does work.

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me the same results as textField.textWidth. Really annoying if you can't / want to use autoSize but need the exact with of a textfield with a certain formatting…

Comment: Maybe you could create separated function which creates temporary TextField with autoSize enabled and copied text inside it and then use textWidth? Something like this: https://gist.github.com/krizajb/8fb2aacc68939d8b3dd3f7a1e2a3565b

Answer (score 0):

```
var str:String = "hello world";
mytf.autoSize = true;
mytf.text = str;
trace(mytf.textWidth )
trace (mytf._width)
```

62 and 63.8

Weird:S